# special firewall requirements for Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We are adding a Google map to our web site by using Google Maps API. Are there any special firewall requirements on the web server that we have hosting this site?

Thank you,

Comment: What is "special" depends entirely on what is "standard".

Answer (score 0):

No, there shouldn't be.  Your web server shouldn't need to do anything.  The only requirement might be for your users - basically they have to be able to access the Google servers, something I assume most of them will be able to do!

It's not much different than if you had an  on your page pointing to an external domain.  In this case you'll be doing the same, but with a javascript file instead.